# Selecting all Primefaces menuitems with JQuery

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I want to run some JQuery code when the user clicks on a menu item using Primefaces. I successfully run JQuery because I tested displaying an alert when the document is ready.

Next, I tried this:

```
$(".ui-menuitem").click(function() {
    alert("You pressed a menuitem");
});
```

because as seen in the inspector the menu item belongs to the class ui-menuitem.

[image]

The above code does not work and I do not understand why.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: _"The above code does not work"_ What **does** it do? Any errors? Tried clicking on children of the `<li ...>`?

Comment: The expected behaviour is showing the alert message when a ui-menuitem is clicked.

Comment: I'm not asking what you want it to do but what it actually is doing

Comment: It does nothing

Comment: So what about my the second remark in my first comment above?